# Trying to create a new method in rails and getting a nomethoderror undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
  def create 
    msg = current_user.msgs.build(params[:msg])
    msg.message = msg.message[0..140]
    msg.created_at = Time.now # HACK
    if msg.save
    else
      flash[:error] = "Your article must contain some text."
    end
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

I want to add something like

```
msg.title = msg.title
msg.byline = msg.byline
```

So that I can have a title and byline associated with each message, but if I do I get the error

```
   NoMethodError in Home#index

   Showing /Users/fred/Desktop/demosite/app/views/home/index.html.erb where line #25 raised:

   undefined method `title' for #<msg:0x00000104dbcn90>
```

How do I add title and byline so that I dont get nomethoderrors? Thanks

Comment: what about beginning with the creation of the necessary columns with a db migration?

Comment: Please tag your questions with one or two tags. Tags are used for categorization of questions and as such you should really tag them with `ruby-on-rails` or `ruby-on-rails-3` depending on what your question pertains to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: what?

```
msg = current_user.msgs.build(params[:msg])
msg.message = msg.message[0..140]
msg.created_at = Time.now # HACK
```

This confuses us. Why would you:

1) Limit the message length *in the controller* and not as a `before_save` on the model?

```
before_save :only_140_characters

def only_140_characters
  self.message = self.message[0..140]
end
```

2) Set `created_at` yourself *in the controller*? This is taken care of by Rails automatically. When a record is created, the `created_at` field will be set to a value by ActiveRecord. Similarly, when you update a record `updated_at` will be set to the current time as well. Rails will only do this if your fields actually exist.

---

Now on to the real question: Why are you getting that undefined method error?

apneadiving points out correctly in the comments you need to add a migration to add that column to the `messages` table. You can do this by running this command:

```
rails g migration add_title_to_messages title:string
```

Then by running `rake db:migrate` will that column be added to the `messages` table in the database. Keep in mind that you'll need to run `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate` to add it to your production database too, if you are at that point.